# how to increase the variable in a loop in TCL?

Tags: loops, tcl

I have the following code in TCL:

```
set counter 1

for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i 1} {
    set temp $counter
    incr temp 1
    incr counter 2 
}
```

for each loop, the `counter` is increased by 2, and `temp` is increased by 1 based on the value of `counter`, but the value of `counter` and `temp` is:

```
counter 1 temp 2 in the first loop
counter 3 temp 3 in the second loop
counter 5 temp 4 in the third loop
```

The expected value is:

```
counter 1 temp 2 in the first loop
counter 3 temp 4 in the second loop
counter 5 temp 6 in the third loop
```

what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Can't reproduce what you're saying it gives. Could you include the `puts` in your code? You might be misplacing them?

Comment: Where do you check the values of $counter and $temp?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you set temp inside the loop, it looks like you set it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you use the value:

```
set counter 1
for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i 1} {
    set temp $counter
    puts "A: counter = $counter, temp = $temp"
    incr temp 1
    puts "B: counter = $counter, temp = $temp"
    incr counter 2 
    puts "C: counter = $counter, temp = $temp"
}
```

When I run that, I get:

```
A: counter = 1, temp = 1
B: counter = 1, temp = 2
C: counter = 3, temp = 2
A: counter = 3, temp = 3
B: counter = 3, temp = 4
C: counter = 5, temp = 4
A: counter = 5, temp = 5
B: counter = 5, temp = 6
C: counter = 7, temp = 6
```

It looks to me like you want the values from the position where `puts "B:…"` is located.